# In Carousel i want to show 3 divs but when i click i want to move 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Carousel where it has 3 items and each item contains 3 divs. normally in a click the total item will move but in a click I want to move only one Div is it possible?

```
<div class="carousel-inner pull-left slides_wrap">
    <div class="active item img_slide slide">
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item img_slide slide">
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item img_slide slide">
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
        <div>some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything is possible - well, nearly.

Comment: Just don't wrap 3 div into one ? I mean, put all you div at the same level and give them class="item img_slide slide".

Comment: which carousel are you using, if you look at the api and it is a decent carousel it will usually give you options that will be something like slides to show and slides to rotate

Comment: Bootstrap carousel iam using

Comment: Actually I want show 3divs but need to move one div that is is the problem enguerranws

Answer (score 0):

By using carousel properties it is possible :

```
$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        easing: 'linear',
        animation: 750,
        speed: 700,
        scroll: 1, 
        wrap: 'circular',
        cycle: true,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
```

Comment: Does he use jCarousel ?

Comment: he can use either .carousel() or jcarousel().

Comment: I am using bootstrap carousel